# Error with infinite loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, while-loop, infinite

Many times I run this, there is an infinite loop problem, but I simply cannot find out what/where it is. Other times, it works fine. During the infinite error runs the program is not even running the initial part where I tell the program to display the arrayList.  I have an arrayList called dailyPlanetStreet filled with objects of either class Goodguy Badguy Person or NormalGuy. In my removing mechanism below, if there is a normalguy/person on one side of the bad guy, i remove that person/normalguy. If there is a normalguy/person on both sides, i randomly remove either one. Also, every time I remove one, I randomly move another person/normal guy from daily planet street to another arraylist called safety land.

For example, an infinite error run might look like this:

```
8
8
8
8
8
8
```

Please help me find the problem

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class GothamLikeAdventureTown 
{
    static int y=5;
    static int x=3;

    static ArrayList<Person> dailyPlanetStreet=new ArrayList<Person>();
    static ArrayList<Person> safetyLand=new ArrayList<Person>();
    static ArrayList<Person> unfortunatelyFatallyWoundedPeople=new ArrayList<Person>();

    public static void rescue() {
        int goodpos=0;
        int randompos=(int)(Math.random()*dailyPlanetStreet.size());
        for (int counter1=0; counter1<dailyPlanetStreet.size(); counter1++){
            if (dailyPlanetStreet.get(counter1).name()!="Kent Clark") {goodpos=counter1; }
        }
        dailyPlanetStreet.add(randompos,dailyPlanetStreet.remove(goodpos));

    }



    public static void tosafety() {
        System.out.println("Got here!");
        int outer=12;
        while (outer!=12){
        int randompos=(int)(Math.random()*dailyPlanetStreet.size());
        if ((dailyPlanetStreet.get(randompos).name()!="Clark Kent") &&  (dailyPlanetStreet.get(randompos).name()!="James Kalvin")) 
        {
            System.out.println("Got into the loop!");
            safetyLand.add(dailyPlanetStreet.remove(randompos));
            outer=12;
        } }
    }
    public static void  remove(int deletepos) {
        unfortunatelyFatallyWoundedPeople.add(dailyPlanetStreet.remove(deletepos)); 
    }

    public static void display(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        for (int z=0; z<dailyPlanetStreet.size(); z++)
        {
            if (dailyPlanetStreet.get(z) instanceof BadGuy) System.out.println("badguy");
            else if (dailyPlanetStreet.get(z) instanceof GoodGuy) System.out.println("goodguy");
            else if (dailyPlanetStreet.get(z) instanceof NormalGuy) System.out.println("normal guy");
            else if (dailyPlanetStreet.get(z) instanceof Person) System.out.println("person");
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
        {
        String[] firstname= {"a ", "b", "c", "d","e","f","g","h","i","j"};
        String[] lastname= {"k ", "l", "m", "n","o","p","q","r","s","t"};
        while (y==x){
            y=(int)(Math.random()*10);
            x=(int)(Math.random()*10);

        }



        for (int z=0; z<10; z++)
        {
            if (z==y)
                {
                    GoodGuy superMan=new GoodGuy( "This looks like a job for superman!"   , "A lot of them"   ,  true , 10   , "Superman"  , "Clark Kent"  , "plumber" , 100  ,   10,10);
                    dailyPlanetStreet.add(superMan);                    }

            else if (z==x)
                {
                    BadGuy superMan=new BadGuy( "haha"   , "Darkness"   ,  true , 10   , "Batman"  , "James Kalvin"  , "farmer" , 100  ,   10,10);
                    dailyPlanetStreet.add(superMan);
                                                                }   
            else  if (((int)(Math.random()*2)+1)==1)
                 {
                    Person superMan=new Person( firstname[(int)(Math.random()*10)]+lastname[(int)(Math.random()*10)], "teacher", 100  , 10,10);
                    dailyPlanetStreet.add(superMan); 
                 }  
            else 
                {
                    NormalGuy superMan=new NormalGuy( firstname[(int)(Math.random()*10)]+lastname[(int)(Math.random()*10)], "teacher", 100  , 10,10);
                    dailyPlanetStreet.add(superMan); 
                }
        }

        display();


        while (dailyPlanetStreet.size()>2){
        for (int counter=0; counter<dailyPlanetStreet.size(); counter++){
            if (dailyPlanetStreet.get(counter).name()=="James Kalvin") 
            {
                if ((counter==0) && (dailyPlanetStreet.get(1).name()=="Clark Kent")) {}
                else if ((counter==0) && (dailyPlanetStreet.get(1).name()!="Clark Kent")) {System.out.println("yo"); remove(counter+1);display();rescue();} 
                else if ((counter==dailyPlanetStreet.size()-1) && (dailyPlanetStreet.get(dailyPlanetStreet.size()-2).name()=="Clark Kent")) {System.out.println("yo"); tosafety();rescue();display();}
                else if ((counter==dailyPlanetStreet.size()-1) && (dailyPlanetStreet.get(dailyPlanetStreet.size()-2).name()!="Clark Kent")) {System.out.println("yo");remove(counter-1);tosafety();rescue();display();}
                else if  (dailyPlanetStreet.get(counter+1).name()=="Clark Kent") {System.out.println("yo");remove(counter-1);tosafety();rescue();display();}
                else if (dailyPlanetStreet.get(counter-1).name()=="Clark Kent") {System.out.println("yo");remove(counter+1); tosafety();rescue();display();}
                else if ((dailyPlanetStreet.get(counter-1).name()!="Clark Kent")&& (dailyPlanetStreet.get(counter+1).name()!="Clark Kent")) 
                {
                    if (((int)(Math.random()*2))==1) {System.out.println("yo");remove(counter+1); tosafety();rescue();display();}
                    else {System.out.println("yo");remove(counter-1);  tosafety();rescue();display();}
                } 

                }
            }
        System.out.println(dailyPlanetStreet.size());
        }


        System.out.println("hi");

        }   

}
```

Comment: [how to compare `String` in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: It is not a duplicate! The OP has been advised to ask another question because the topic had changed. Please read carefully when flagging questionse :-/

Answer (score 0):

You compare `String` with `==` instead of `.equals`, this is a common mistake and does not work.

For example in your while loop:

```
if (dailyPlanetStreet.get(counter).name()=="James Kalvin")
```

should be changed to:

```
if (dailyPlanetStreet.get(counter).name().equals("James Kalvin"))
```

as well as all other occurrences where you compare strings.

**EDIT**

On the problem with the infinite loop:

Your while loop runs until `.size()` is smaller than 2. But in your while loop you only do something if one of the `.name()` values in `dailyPlanetStreet` is `"James Kalvin"`. From what I see those values are generated/selected randomly. So if you happen to not get any James Kalvins you will loop forever there.

To be able to tell more about why exactly it loops forever I would have to see the constructor for `BadGuy` that you're using..

**EDIT 2**

After looking at the comment below, I see that all the `if else if`clauses in the while loop start with a condition that's comparing String's with `==`. Therefore none of those will return true and nothing will be done. Please change all your `....name()=="Something"` to `....name().equals("Something")`.

Comment: I was told offline by the OP that these two lines ensure that you'll get a James Kalvin: BadGuy superMan=new BadGuy( "haha"   , "Darkness"   ,  true , 10   , "Batman"  , "James Kalvin"  , "farmer" , 100  ,   10,10);
                    dailyPlanetStreet.add(superMan);